# Hint for a Sequence of Free Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence, free-modules

Could someone please give me a hint for this problem?

The following sequence is exact:

$0 \rightarrow A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C \xrightarrow{h} D \xrightarrow{i} E \xrightarrow{j} F \to 0$.

Prove: If $A, B, D, E$, and $F$ are free R-modules, then $C$ is torsion-free. (R is a PID, particularly: $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$.)

This is my attempt:

$0 \rightarrow \text{coker}f \rightarrow C \rightarrow \text{im}h \to 0$.

I know $\text{im}h$ is torsion-free since it is a subgroup of a free group. I know that cokernel of $f$ is B/im$f$. And if k$\sigma$ is an element of im$f$, then showing that $\sigma$ is an element of im$f$ would prove the result, where k is an element of the ring.

Comment: What is the ring here?  Some arbitrary commutative ring?  Some arbitrary integral domain?  $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Oh, thanks! I'm pretty sure the ring is the one from the previous problem. I added it to the question.

Comment: If this is a textbook question, can you give the source and page reference?

Comment: It's not. It's from my teacher... which makes me a little suspicious of whether the question is wrong.

Comment: @BrianMoehring And it's just supposed to involve looking at kernels and images and making a short exact sequence. So that worked for the image, but I don't know what to do for the other side of C.

Comment: Just as a disclaimer: I was asking about a textbook reference to make sure the context is correct.  My inability to post a solution should imply nothing about whether the statement itself is correct.

Comment: @BrianMoehring OK. Thank you. I only remember my teacher saying to show the kernel and image are free, and then the middle will be free.

Comment: In the context of a general PID $R$, we have the counterexample $0 \to 2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/(2\mathbb{Z}) \to 0$, so if it's true in your context, it has to use some more properties of $R$.  (this might be considered an answer to the given question depending on how I interpret the context, but since it's possible $R$ is more specialized, I've decided to delete my answer in favor of a comment)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you! That's perfect.